# Придаточное причины при отрицании

Tags: синтаксис, сослагательное-наклонение

В Интернете нашла маленький "комментарий" о том, что в придаточных причины может употребляться сослагательное наклонение, если причина негируется.

Например,

*Сказал же он это **не потому, чтобы / не оттого чтобы** заботился о нищих, но потому что был вор*.

Информационный поиск в Сети не дает, к сожалению, ничего. Большинство найденных примеров содержат "*не потому, что*", а не "*не потому, чтобы*".  Можно это объяснить как "устаревший" вариант?

Большое спасибо!

Comment: Я немножко подправила вопрос, но так и не угадала, что такое "негируется"...

Comment: Спасибо, @Galina Avanesova! но я совсем не хотела использовать кавычки : ) просто у меня нет кнопки с штрихом над "и"

Comment: Галя, негация, негировать — отрицание, снятие двойственности и про­тивопоставления.(от "негатив"). Здесь  "потому чтобы" - "не потому чтобы"-отрицание.

Comment: Анонимушка, если я навредила своей правкой, поправь, пожалуйста, в обратную сторону и извини; Люсенька, спасибо за разъяснения: я настолько не поверила неизвестному слову, что даже не слазила  в словарь; плакайу.

Comment: Нашла такой контекст: "...значеніе нѣсколькихъ поколѣній, ибо яко мы всѣ на этомъ свѣтѣ смертны, то власть отъ однихъ на другихъ переходитъ, я ни гетманская, ни королевская не могутъ ея негировать или принуждать кого-либо оппонировать ей". И: "В русском языке нет слова «негировать». Даже ваша логическая терминология страшно далека от принятой к использованию в отечественной среде..." https://vk.com/wall-41758951_5105

Comment: @Galina: про исправление - все в порядке, не беспокоитесь! наоборот, Вы поставили тильды там где надо, спасибо : )
про слово "негировать": моя вина - я взяла глагол из своего языка и приложила русское окончание глагола к нему, потому что не знала как сказать по-русски =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, это устаревший союз, сейчас употребляется и  как разговорный.
У Пушкина:

Не потому, чтобы прочла,

Не потому, чтоб Грандисона

Она Ловласу предпочла...

Вот в Русской грамматике:

§ 3031.Актуализатором собственно-причинных отношений является отрицание при потому, акцентирующее его лексическую самостоятельность; при этом позицию что обычно занимает союз чтобы. В таких построениях, отмечаемых преимущественно в языке писателей XIX в., отрицаемая причина, как правило, противопоставлена причине истинной.
   Она остановилась и не тотчас ответила ему - не потому, чтоб она сердилась, а ее мысли были далеко (Тург.); Портрет пишется не потому,чтобы черты живого человека не удовлетворяли нас, а для того, чтобы помочь нашему воспоминанию о живом человеке (Черн.); Это увещаниеоказывает свое действие не потому, чтобы оно заключало что-нибудь действительно убедительное, а потому, что Иудушка и сам видит, чтоон зарапортовался, что лучше как-нибудь миром покончить день (С.-Щ.); Бывая в Мугайском заводе, я всегда останавливаюсь в... домикеФатеевны не потому, чтобы сама Фатеевна или ее дом мне особенно нравились, а просто по старой привычке (М.-Сиб.).
   Союз чтобы в позиции что возможен и при отсутствии отрицания при потому. В этих случаях значение достаточного основания контаминируется со значением цели: Мы привели потому это, чтобы читатель мог сам видеть, что это случилось совершенно по необходимости(Гоголь).
[АКАДЕМИЯ НАУК СССР ИНСТИТУТ РУССКОГО ЯЗЫКА РУССКАЯ ГРАММАТИКА](http://rusgram.narod.ru/3026-3042.html)

Comment: большое спасибо за ответ и за линк! : )